# Intercept Adobe flash player

Tags: flash, winapi, com, activex, hook

I am building an application which uses the IE activex control to host youtube videos, using the youtube IFRAME based player API.

However, I wish to prevent links in the control from launching external browser windows - How do I do this?

I thought I might hook ShellExecute in my process, but this is never called. Nor is CreateProcess()
I used an API tracer and it seems like it is using COM interfaces to launch IE.

Any pointers (pun intended) on how I can go forward? Maybe I'll have to hook cocreateinstance and provide a faux object of my own making instead?